# Clear Interval + message and replace with a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

How can I clean interval+message and replace those with a link.

Below code is opening a link after 10 seconds in new window. When I get back to that page, message showing **You will redirect in 0 seconds**

What I want is, after 10 seconds (after opening link in new tab) the counter and message will replace with a new message and link. i.e. **If you are not redirected to the link [Click Here](https://www.google.com/) to go to the link.**

```js
var count = 10;
var counter;

function start(){
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
 
function timer() {   
  var output = document.getElementById("displaySeconds");
  output.innerHTML = count;   
  count--;    
  if (count < 0) { 
    clearInterval(counter);    
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
    return;
  }
} 

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

```html
<br>You will redirect in <span id="displaySeconds">10</span> seconds.<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate `div` with the text when the user is not redirected with the `display` property set to none (`display: none`). When the timer expires, you can hide the original text and show the alternative version.

There is a working jsfiddle below. I modified the counter to 4 seconds not to wait too much, you can adjust it how you want.

```js
var count = 4;
var counter;

function start() {
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function timer() {
  var output = document.getElementById("displaySeconds");
  output.innerHTML = count;
  count--;
  if (count < 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
    
    let originalText = document.getElementById("original");
    let noRedirectText = document.getElementById("noredirect");
    
    originalText.style.display = "none";
    noRedirectText.style.display = "block";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="original">
    You will be redirected in <span id="displaySeconds">4</span> seconds.
  </div>

  <div style="display: none" id="noredirect">
    If you are not redirected click <a href="https://www.google.com">here</a> to go to the link.
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, It's working well in my pc browser. But not working in my mobile browsers Like Opera Mini. (It may be for data saving mode or lite browser that don't support java, not sure.) Can you help me a little more so that I can display ** that Link ** if the browser can't run the counter ?

Comment: I tired this code `<noscript> If you are not redirected to the link <a href="https://www.google.com">Click Here</a> to go to the link. </noscript>` which is working any browser that disabled java. But not working in Opera Mini android browser and some lightweight browser even they have java enabled. Is there any solution for this kind of lightweight browser?

Comment: @user3137451 When browsing the Web in Opera Mini JavaScript is processed by the proxy server (opera servers), and is merely rendered on the device. Before the page is sent to the mobile device, its `onLoad` events are fired and all scripts are allowed a maximum of two seconds to execute. The `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions are disabled, so scripts designed to wait a certain amount of time before executing will not execute at all

Comment: @user3137451 Also, reffer to the language as `javascript`, not java, since they are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add code to the interval function that hides the first message and shows the other.

```js
var count = 5;
var output = document.getElementById("displaySeconds");
var counter = null;

function timer() {   
  output.textContent = count;   
  count--;    
  if (count < 0) { 
    clearInterval(counter);    
    window.open("https://www.google.com");

    // Hide the first message and show the second:
    document.querySelector(".redirect1").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".redirect2").classList.remove("hidden");    
  }
} 

addEventListener("load", function(){
  couner = setInterval(timer, 1000);
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="redirect1">You will redirect in <span id="displaySeconds">5</span> seconds.</div>

<!-- The following is initially hidden because of the CSS class -->
<div class="redirect2 hidden">If you aren't redirected, click <a href="#">here</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function replaces the current text with your required text if the redirect was not able to take place.

```js
var count = 10;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
var output = document.getElementById("displaySeconds");
var container = document.getElementById("container");
 
 function timer() {
     count--;
     if (count === 0) {
         stopTimer();
     }
     output.innerHTML = count;
 };

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(counter);
  window.open("https://www.google.com");
  container.innerHTML = ' If you are not redirected to the link <a href="https://www.google.com">Click Here</a> to go to the link.';
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 You will redirect in <span id="displaySeconds">10</span> seconds.
</div>
```